# HammerJS vertical swipe and VERTICAL scroll simultaneously

Tags: javascript, angular, mobile, hammer.js

I have a fullpage web site on angular 5, which do pagination by vertical swipe down and up (on desctop version is listening for wheel events). On mobile I met a serious problem with non-hiding address bar because of no scrolling happens on page (page have a size of viewport). So my structure looks like this:

```
<div (swipeup)="fnc()" (swipedown)="fnc()">
    Container handling vertical swipes and has touch-action: pan-y property 
    and 100vh height
    <component>Container handles horizontal swipes inside components</component>
</div>
```

My current Hammer config:

```
mc.get('pinch').set({enable: false});
mc.get('rotate').set({enable: false});
mc.get('swipe').set({direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL});
mc.get('pan').set({direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL});
```

And `{ "touchAction": "pan-y" }` seted to container which handles vertical swipes.

With this config I'm able to scroll with hiding of address bar but vertical swipe doesn't work (or it fires super rare in strange circumstances). But I want vertical swipe to fire every time when scrolling is over and not possible (when I scroll to the bottom and my address bar became hidden it should fire next swipe in the same direction).

I will be grateful for any help or advice on how to do this in different way.

Comment: Have you found a way how to do it? I am struggling with it now...

Answer (score 0):

```
new Hammer(element, {
   inputClass: Hammer.TouchInput,
});
```

this try

Comment: Whilst this code may be useful it would be much better if the answer explained how it works and how it solves the question.